# Define variables inside if condition in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am passing a value from a servlet to JSP using follows, which returns Integer value.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(USER_OFFICE, user.getOffice().getId());
```

I can get this value in JSP:

```
<%=session.getAttribute("USER_OFFICE")%>
```

Now I need to show some text in JSP based on `USER_OFFICE` values:

- "Hello Police" - if `USER_OFFICE` value is 1
- "Hello Doctor" - if `USER_OFFICE` value is 2
- "Hello Engineer" - if `USER_OFFICE` value is 3

Comment: The answers given have shown how you *can* do this but please don't.  This is the exact kind of logic that should live on the server side and the front-end should just present it.  Why don't you have your servlet calculate what the greeting should be and in your JSP expose that value and just display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try EL & taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${1 eq USER_OFFICE}">
       Hello Police
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${2 eq USER_OFFICE}">
        Hello Doctor
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Hello Engineer
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

OR without taglib:

```
${1 eq USER_OFFICE ? "Hello Police" : (2 eq USER_OFFICE ? "Hello Doctor" : "Hello Engineer")}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%

String userOffice= session.getAttribute("USER_OFFICE")

if(userOffice.equals("1")){
   out.print("Hello Police")
}else if(userOffice.equals("2")){
  out.print("Hello Doctor")
}else if(userOffice.equals("3")){
  out.print("Hello Engineer")
}

%>
```

In this way you can write scriptlet in your JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scriptlet` tag.

```
<%
    String value = session.getAttribute("USER_OFFICE");
    if(value.equals(1)){
           out.print("Hello Police");
    }else if(value.equals("2")){
           out.print("Hello Police");
    }else if(value.equals("3")){
           out.print("Hello Engineer");
    }

%>
```

P.S. You have mentioned 1, 2 and 3, which I didn't see earlier.